# MVC Force jQuery validation on group of elements

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

My form I am designing with MVC 4 has mutiple DIVS with many elements in each one.  My objective is to open/close DIVS as the user completes the fields.  However, I want to use the unobtrusive validation on each DIV, rather than the whole form.  Is that possible without checking each element individually?  Maybe using a DIV ID or something?  I don't want to build this massive function to check each and every element in each DIV just so the user can move to the next DIV.

I am trying this and it is not working:

```
 var elems = [];
 var valid = true;
 ("#Contact").find('.text_input').each(function() {
    elems.push(this.id);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i<= elems.length; i++) {
       if ($("#" + elems[i]) != undefined) {
           $("#form1").validate().element("#" + elems[i]))
           if ($("#" + elems[i]).valid()) {
           }
           else {
             valid = false;
           }
        }
   }
```

but I keep getting an undefined error.  The elements in the DIV that have the class text_input are the ones with validation required.

Comment: When would you validate the elements within a div? For example, when the last element in the div loses focus or when you click on a button to show the next div?

Comment: In this case, when the user clicks Next, which calls a function to hide the first div and show the second.  But I want to check the elements in that first div before showing the second one?  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can validate individual controls using `Validator.element(element)` - [see documentation here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element#element), so you could use the following approach (you haven't posted the views html so can't write the actual code for you)

In the Next button click event

1. Select all the the controls within the
   associated `div` - e.g.  `var controls = $(this).closest('div').find('input, textarea, select');`
2. In an `$.each` loop, call `$("form").validate().element($(this));`
3. If necessary, test if valid with `$(this).valid();`
4. If everything is valid, hide the current div and display the next

**Edit** (example added)

View

```
<div class="section">
  <h2>Section 1</h2>
  .... // Your inputs and validation
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
  <div class="error"></div>
  <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <h2>Section 2</h2>
  .... // Your inputs and validation
  <div class="error"></div>
  <button type="button" class="next">Next</button>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <h2>Section 3</h2>
  .... // Your inputs and validation
  <div class="error"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="next">Submit</button> // submit button for last section
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section:not(:first-of-type) {
    display:none;
}
```

Script

```
$('button').click(function () {
  var container = $(this).closest('.section');
  var isValid = true;     
  $.each(container.find('input'), function () {
    $('form').validate().element($(this));
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
      isValid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (isValid) {
    container.next('.section').show().find('input').first().focus();
    container.hide();
  } else {
    container.find('.error').text('please complete');
  }
});
```

Comment: check my edits and let me know why that doesn't work

Comment: There is no reason to put it into an array. After `var controls = ...` then `$.each(controls, function(index, item) { $("#form1").validate().element($(this));` - or it might need to be `..element($(this)[0]);` - not sure without testing

Comment: Could you possibly write out the function for me?

Comment: Its late - I'll have a look tommorow

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Great solution. Very simple and not much code.