# Client-Side Validation with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, wizard

I need to create a multi-step wizard using ASP.NET MVC.

After thinking about this a while, I feel like the most efficient solution is to put the content for all my wizard steps in a single view, and just step through them by hiding and showing elements using jQuery.

But one area I'm not totally at ease with is MVC validation. How could I validate each step this way? Seems like I won't know for sure if the data is valid until the final step is completed and the entire page is posted back to the server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate individual controls using `Validator.element(element)` - [see documentation here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element#element). An example of the approach I think you are taking is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Comment: What is at that link? Is jQuery Validator a built-in part of jQuery, or a third-party plug in? And how does that work with MVC (I don't see anything on that page about MVC)?

Comment: The `validate()` method is part of `jquery-validate.js` (and you also need `jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js` for client side unobtrusive validation)

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I understand. This is included out of the box with current versions of MVC. Is that right?

Comment: Both files should be in the `Scripts` folder of your project when you create a new MVC project.