# How to create a wizard based registration in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a wizard based registration in asp.net mvc which consists of around 5 steps. I'm not sure how to do this, I was about to create 5 actions and store the values in session but it doesn't seem good and is more error prone I think.

What would you suggest?

Comment: There are numerous ways this could be done. One option is have a single form and show/hide sections as [shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Answer (score 0):

If you create an UnregisteredUser database table and update fields from the 5 steps of the wizard then you can use this data at a later date.

For example, if you collect the email address in step one but the unregistered user fails to complete the wizard you might decide to send them an email a few days later saying:

*"We noticed that you didn't complete our registration a couple of days ago, would you like to complete it now?"* with a link back into the wizard.

It'd also let you do some analysis on the data to see if specific demographics were dropping out at a specific stage. For example, non-US people being forced to enter an address in US address format.