# How to prevent a modal popup windows from submitting the form in-case it have validation errors

Tags: jquery, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc5 web application, and i am implementing CRUD operations using Bootstrap & WebGrid.

now my Create action methods looks as follow:-

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            var phone = new Phone();
            return PartialView("Create", phone);
        }


        // POST: /Phone/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(Phone phone)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Phones.Add(phone);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            return Json(phone, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and the Index view which have a Create button that will open the popup window:-

```
 <div class="pull-right col-lg-1">   
                <a class="btn btn-success" data-modal="" href="/Phone/Create" id="btnCreate">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>      
                </a>
            </div>
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade in'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/scripts/appjs/phones.js")
}
```

an the phones.js is :-

```
  $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {        
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');

                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });


    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $('#progress').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#progress').hide();
                        $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

the Create view:-

```
  @model MvcBootstrapCrud.Models.Phone

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Phone</h3>
    </div>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Model, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model, new { @class = "form-control required" })
                        <div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Model)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Company, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Company, new { @class = "form-control required" })
                        <div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Company)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Price, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "form-control required" })
                        <div>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Price)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <span id="progress" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
                <img src="/images/wait.gif" alt="wiat" />
                Wait..
            </span>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
            <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    }
    <script>
        $("form").removeData("validator");
        $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    </script>
```

and the Phone model class:-

```
public class Phone
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        [Key]
        public int PhoneId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Model Name")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Price")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem i am facing is that when the Create modal popup form is shown , and the user leave a Required field empty ,  a validation error will be shown beside the field (as defined in the [Required] data annotation). but the validation error will not prevent the popup from submitting the form when the user click on Save button ,and the Post Create action method are going to be called even with the validation error being shown.. so can anyone adivce on this please?
Thanks

Comment: In your `submit` function you could try calling `$('form').valid()` and if it returns `false` then cancel it

Comment: Note you may also need to call `.validate()` on the form before calling `.valid()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you please adivce where exactly i need to add $('form').valid() & .validate() ? thanks

Comment: Haven't had a chance to test, but before `$('#progress').show();` - `$('form').validate(); if (!$('form').valid()} { return false; } ...`

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried this   function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $('form').validate(); 
            if (!$('form').valid())
        { return false; } 
            $('#progress').show();
            $.ajax({  . but still the form will be submitted even if there are validation errors .. can u adivce please?

Comment: Just did a quick test - I could not make it work with `if (!$('form').valid()) {..` but when I changed the selector to a specific control `if (!$('#MyControl').valid()) {..` it worked. I'll do some more testing on this tomorrow

Comment: @StephenMuecke but now if the form is submitted successfully i will get the following message inside the web browser {"success":true} rather than doing a  location.reload(); ??

Comment: Added answer for the client side validation. Not sure why your getting  that result (it must be valid in order to return `{success: true }` which means it should run the `if` block, not the `else` block - are you sure that' the exact code?). But why are you calling `location.reload();` anyway - sort of defeats the purpose of using ajax?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) calling `$('form').valid()` should return false if there are any validation errors however after running a few tests, this sometimes throws a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` (the result of `JSON.parse(data)` where `data` is `undefined`). Not sure why this is only happening sometimes. You can however validate each individual element and prevent the ajax call if any are invalid

```
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
  var isValid = true; // assume all OK
  $('form').validate(); // perform validation on the form
  $('input[type="text"]').each(function (index, item) { // could change selector to suit e.g $('input, textarea').each(..            
    if (!$(this).valid()) {
      isValid = false; // signal errors
      return false; // break out of loop   
    }
  })
  if (!isValid) {
    return false; // exit
  }
  // Good to submit
  $('#progress').show();
    $.ajax({
      url: this.action,
      .....
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help. Your code worked for me 100%. But I have these two questions (if you can advise on them); First, is it a recommended approach to validate each individual elements and prevent the ajax call if any are invalid ? or at the end I should find another approach?. Second question , you mentioned that I should not use location.reload()because it defeats the purpose of using ajax and you are correct, so should I for example display a dialog box saying something such as “Your record was added successfully” and then reload the underlying grid to get a grid with the added item ??

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with validating individual elements (internally that's what jquery-validate-unobtrusive is doing for a standard submit anyway) and its common with a wizard/multi-step form as per [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Comment: My approach would be to call the server to insert the new record in the database then manually update the DOM in the the success function (e.g add a new table row based on the values in the form). Alternatively have the method return a partial view containing the html of the new table row and update the DOM with it).

Comment: One final note. `Phone` class has a property named `Model`. Its quite common for POST methods to have the signature `public ActionResult Create(MyClass model)` which in your case, binding would fail because the method parameter name is the same name as a property. Just wanted to make you aware of it :)

Comment: thanks for the help. First question if i will be validating individual elements then there is not any need for calling this inside my script " $('form').validate(); "? is this correct?

Comment: Second question. at the beginning i was thinking the same way to return a partial view containing a table row , then update the table with the newly added row . but this raised a user experience problem, because by defualt i sort the skills grid Ascending by Company . so now let say a user added a new phone with a company that start with Z then this row will be added as the first row in the Phone table ,, and the user will need to reload the Phone table to get the correct sort.. so do you find this as UI problem ?or it is fine?

Comment: @johnG, I think you still need to call it, but not 100% sure (my undertanding is that `.validate()` performs the validation on each element and then `.valid()` just returns true or false) - you will need to debug and test

Comment: i tried removing the $('form').validate(); and my partial view validation will work fine ,, can you adivce ?

Comment: @johnG, there is no reason you cannot use javascript/jquery to determine where to add the row based on your sorting and insert the row at the correct location - but that's really the subject of a new question if your having problems (I would just do a loop on each existing table row, get the name, test it against the new name to determine where to insert it)

Comment: ok i agree with u this is a new question. but returning back to the first question now i removed the " $('form').validate(); " and the form validation is working well,, so does this means that there is something unusual because as u mentioned the " $('form').validate(); " should be doing the real validation and not validating each element separately ?

Comment: @johnG, I think you need need to test this a bit. If you have done any editing of the controls then internally, validation will have been performed (that's how the error messages are displayed) so `.validate()` is probably not necessary, but if you just click the button first it may be necessary - I'm just not sure of the actual order that the various jquery-validate and jquery-validate-unobtrusive events are called.

Comment: no even if i click on the Save button when the partial view first rendered , then i will receive the validation errors successfully ..

Comment: i have noted something strange when i did extensive testing , seems that i can submit invalid form if i click on the keyboard Enter button inside the partial view ? so the form will be submitted even if it contain validation errors,, so is there a way to prevent the form for being submitted when i click on the Enter on my keyboard, to have the same behavior when click on the Save button ?

Comment: One option is to handle the keydown event and cancel it, e.g. `$(window).keydown(function (e) { if (event.keyCode == 13) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }});`

Comment: where exactly i need to add this statement ? i am starting to questioning my self if i need to do all these things manually (for stop submitting the partial view which have validation errors) ... Becuase if i render the view as regular view (not partial) all of these will be handled automatically ...

Comment: It would just go in the script block of the main view (in a document.ready block)

Answer (score 1):

**Please change the Controller PhoneController.cs**.

From

```
       // POST: /Phone/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(Phone phone)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Phones.Add(phone);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            return Json(phone, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

To

```
        // POST: /Phone/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Phone phone)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Phones.Add(phone);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            return PartialView("Create", phone);
        }
```

This solved the issue for me.