# JQuery Validation for multi-step registration asp.net mvc pages

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Basically i have two divs which i am using to show only one div for each page. So on load i am loading first (id="divSection1").On click of Next button, the JQuery should validate the fields on the first page only. But here in my case, its validating the second div elements which are hidden.**This is issue 1**.
Jquery needs to validate only  the viewable div on the page

**2nd Issue is:**
I have design which has 3 Text boxes with same class name but different id's and different name's.
I have to make sure the user to enter at least one of the text boxes, present in divSection2. I tried to use $.validate.addmethod(). Looks like i am missing something:

```
<form action="~/Home/About" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="formId"   
onkeyup="formkeyup();">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Registration Form</legend>
<div class="section" id="divSection1" >
    <h3>Step 1: Password</h3>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.Password" onkeyup=" return ValidateField() "/>
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            <input type="password" name="confirmpwd" id="confirmpwd" autocomplete="off" value="@Model.ConfirmPwd" onkeyup=" return ValidateField() "/>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
<div id="divSection2" class="section">
    <input type="text" name="input1" class="answertextbox" />
    <input type="text" name="input2" class="answertextbox" />
    <input type="text" name="input3" class="answertextbox" />
</div>
 <div>
 <div id="errorMessage" style="display: inline-block; padding-bottom: 8px;">
                            @Html.ValidationSummary()
                        </div>
                    </div>
<p>
 <input type="button" id="NextId" name="NextId" value="Next" 
 onClick="Validate()/>
</p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
function Validate()
{

  $('#formId').validate({
        rules: {
            ignore: ":hidden",
            pwd: {
                required: true
            },
            confirmPwd: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Username: "Please enter Username",
            pwd: "Please enter Password",
            confirmPwd: "Please enter ConfirmPassword"
        }
    });


    var numCount = 0;
    $.validator.addMethod('answertextbox', function (val, el) {

        var $module = $(el).parents('div.panel');
        var length = $module.find('.answertextbox k-input:filled').length;
       //checking if any one of the text is entered
        if (length > 0) {
            numCount ++;
        }
    }, setMessage(numCount));

    jQuery.validator.addClassRules('answertextbox k-input', {
        'answertextbox': true
    });

}

 function setMessage(count) {
    if (count === 0) {
        $("#errorMessage").html('<span style="color:red">Please fill out at least one of these fields.</span>');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Basically i tried it using Data Annotations, but it isn't working for me. I had the Validation messages on the respective properties- Password, ConfirmPassword..etc
!validator.element(this) - is always returning true,even when there is no value in the input textbox.
Here is the code:

```
function Validate()
 {
  var validator = $("form").validate(); 
  var anyError = false;
        $('.section:visible').find("input").each(function() {
            if (!validator.element(this)) { // validate every input element inside this step
                anyError = true;
            }

        });

    if (anyError)
        return false; // exit if any error found
}
```

Any help/suggestion/inputs on this is really helpful.

Thanks,

WH

Comment: Why are you not using the inbuilt html helpers including `ValidationMessageFor()`? (your model has a property named `Password` but then you manually create a control named `pwd` so your model will not be bound on post back!). You can a multi-step wizard/form where you validate one section at a time as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Comment: @StephenMuecke-Thanks for the response. Please find my edit

Comment: Adding the `[Required]` attribute and using `@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)` should work fine (so long as you have the relevant js files included. But you have to call `.valid()` to test if an element is valid or no,t as per the link in my last comment (and you should not be calling `var validator = $("form").validate();` which validates all controls)

Comment: @StephenMuecke- I did it, but still it isn't working..

Comment: @StephenMuecke- do i need to have same viewmodel for both the divs( divSection1, divSection2)?..Currently i have two models for each div. Do you think that could be an issue here?

Comment: Having 2 view models is going to create problems using strongly typed helpers, and when you post back (what would you bind to?) so you should have one view model with all properties, but that would not explain why your client code is not working. The answer in the link is from a working project (and just tested it again) so something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. Its working now-

I was using html `<input>`for password and confirm password. But when i used the HTML helpers, it started working-

```
@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password,
                    new
                    {
                        id = "password",
                        autocomplete = "off",
                        onkeyup = " return ValidateField() "
                    })
```