# How to disable validation on button click in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to know that how can the validation be disabled on the button click.
I found some solutions in stackoverflow but these solutions are not working.

One solution I found is to put class="cancel" for submit button

and the other I found is as follows:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function () {
                $('form').validate().cancelSubmit = false;
            });
});
```

Both of these solutions are not working for me. In the second solution intellisense is not even showing cancelSubmit after validate().

I also want to know how can I make validation work in mvc as it works with validationgroup in asp.net that is some validations are bound with one button and the others are bound with the second button.

Thanks....

Comment: Just because Intellisense doesn't show the command, does not mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you mean by _validation be disabled on the button click_? Are you wanting to allow the form to be submitted even if its invalid?

Comment: @Andrei V But I tried cancelSubmit it was not working

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I have two buttons one I want to bind with some validations and the other I want to bind with other validations as we do with validationgroup in asp.net

Comment: Do you mean your trying to a kind of wizard where your want to validate one group of controls before moving to another group of controls?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke you are absolutely right.........

Comment: OK. I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) is probably along the lines of what you want (and you need to structure your question better)