# MVC Partial View Tab In Tab Strip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tabs, partial-views

I'm trying to setup a tab strip in HTML/jQuery that will hold a separate partial view in each tab that has its own form, fields, and has validation. I want the user only to processed to the next tab if the viewmodel is valid. I have no trouble with hiding and showing the tabs through jQuery, but I would rather use the MVC pattern than use a bunch of Ajax and JSON for the models.

I have a layout view, a base view that uses the layout, and partial views rendered on the main view, which act as independent tabs. I've tried declaring viewmodels of the partials inside on the main viewmodel, and passing models into action methods, but I can't get the data from the view in a hierarchical manner that makes sense. I'm coming from years of webforms development, and I'm fairly new at MVC.

Any insight on how to do this?

Comment: This is pretty complex to answer, which is probably why there aren't any. It's a great question though. What you're attempting is definitely doable, but it's a clunky approach. And that's exactly why you're running into difficulties. Might I suggest a re-think? Your UI component is doing too much. I feel that tabs shouldn't be used in this way. Just something to think about.

Comment: It sound like your wanting something like a wizard. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) shows an example of how you could approach that.