# Editing a single entity across different controller views w/out calling db with each action?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I have an object/entity called 'Space'. I want to put each of the different entities (images, details, location, etc) inside 'Space' onto different pages/views so that each part can be edited separately, the user clicks on nav links to edit each section. I don't want to have to fetch the entity from the database every time it posts back to another action. Isn't there a better way to do this? 
Maybe having each one of these as action methods (location, images, details) isn't the correct approach? Is hiding different parts of the page better with javascript? Please advise! I'm trying to model it after airbnb's page that edits a listing...
Ex.

> mysite/managespaces/123/images
>    // you see the form to edit pics for id 123
>   mysite/managespaces/123/location 
>   //here you only edit loc details for id 123
>   mysite/managespaces/123/details 
>   //here details are edited for id 123

etc...

```
public class Space
{
    public int SpaceId { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = false)]
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string AspNetUserRefId { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceOverview Overview { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceDetails Details { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SpaceImage> Images { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceListing Listing { get; set; }

    public virtual SpaceAddress Location { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SpaceReview> Reviews { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Required]
```

Comment: After doing a little research I see that I can use create different div's and hide/show them when a nav link is clicked, but how would I control the action in the url to display the link item as a action without posting back?

Comment: Why are you concerned with getting the object again from the database (which is the normal approach)? You could always use `Session` if hitting the db is expensive (but that might suggest something else is wrong). More to the point is why you are `Space` to a view that only edits `Details` or `Location`?

Comment: My concern with getting the object from the db is speed! With every click on the nav (details, images, overview, etc) I don't want to go back to the database and re fetch the object, that's very redundant. My view will edit all aspects of space, so I should only have to fetch it once! Take a look at airbnb and how you manage your listing, the site doesn't post back every time a you go to a different area of your listing to edit it. THey are hiding/showing different sections I think!! maybe not.

Comment: What do you mean _redundant_? its the standard way. As I said you can always put the object in session between calls and retrieve it from there. But if your view edits all properties of the model, the there should be one view, with one form (why would you have links to separate pages?). Its easier enough to do this showing one part of a form at a time, and you can even make it a wizard, validating each section at time [as per this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097).

Comment: It might be the standard way but I don't think it will be very user friendly if I have to post back every time to edit different parts of the form, even if they are in different visible sections/divs. I just want to emulate what airbnb is doing on their page that allows you to edit a listing. If you can advise me as to their methods or a asp.net mvc equivalent I would be appreciative!

Comment: My comments relate to your question which shows you have links to separate pages. I gave you a link in my last comment to show one option to do this on one page. And there are lots of other options you can consider, such as using ajax to both load and save various sections of the model.

Comment: that you for your help! much appreciated!