# How to get hidden values in httpget in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I am working on wizard type application in mvc, it will help people to book their appointment, first page it has reason for visit, then select doctor like wise it will go and finally book appointment. I have post and get method to maintain the data between pages. This application not maintaining any user specific session instead i am maintaining session based on hospital id(chains of hospital they can book appointment on any hospital, no user based authentication, its hospital id based session maintaining).

My method for session creation is:

```
public AppointmentRequest InitAppointmentRequest(string hospitalId)
{
    var objAppointment = new AppointmentRequest();
    _Appointment_WorkingState = "Appointment.WorkingState" + ":" + hospitalId;
    HttpContext.Current.Session[_Appointment_WorkingState] = objAppointment;
    return objAppointment;
}

public AppointmentRequest GetAppointmentSession(int hospitalId)
{
    _Appointment_WorkingState = "Appointment.WorkingState" + ":" + hospitalId;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session[_Appointment_WorkingState] != null)
        return (AppointmentRequest)HttpContext.Current.Session[_Appointment_WorkingState];
    return null;
    //return RedirectToRouteResult("Index", "Appointment");
}
```

Its working fine, if the user open only one url(http://localhost:53430/?hospitalid=153), not working if the user copy past the same url with different hospital(http://localhost:53430/?hospitalid=152) in the same browser.

If I post the page I am passing the hospitalid from the model and working fine. If do one click for hospital 152, navigate to other hospital 153 in next tab of the same browser and returning back to 152 and click back button its throwing exception because I cant able to get the hospital id is get method.

```
 public ActionResult Index(string hospitalid)
 {
     var appointment = AppointmentRequest.InitAppointmentRequest(hospitalid);
    //some logics
    return view("index");
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("select-appointment-reason")]
public ActionResult AppointmentReason(AppointmentRequest model, FormCollection collection)
{
    var appointment = AppointmentRequest.GetAppointmentSession(model.HospitalId);
    //var appointment = AppointmentRequest.GetCurrent();
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("select-appointment-reason")]
public ActionResult AppointmentReason()
{
    // i need hospital id here to get the exact session.    
    var appointment = AppointmentRequest.GetAppointmentSession(hospitalid);
    return view(appointment);
}
```

In the get method somehow I need to get the hospital id before I call the `getappointmentsession` to get the exact session value. Currently I don't have any hidden field, I come to know, I can get the hidden field values only in post method form collection. I need hospital id in get method, that's is my requirement or any best way to fix this issue.

Comment: A simpler and cleaner solution may be have a single view/form with each step in hidden containers with next/back buttons that show/hide the relevant steps, with the final step having a submit button (no `Session`)

Comment: good suggestion, but we in project completion stage, end up with this kind of issue at the last minute, running out of time, any alternate solution with the existing approach please?.

Comment: Not that I can see, but implementing the single view/form option is not hard ([refer example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097))