# Ajax POST with view model and __RequestVerificationToken errors out

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I have a an MVC 5 page on which I would like to post json data to the controller on a button click via ajax. The function I have to post the data:

```
          var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
          var jsonData = JSON.stringify(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
          var dataString = '{ __RequestVerificationToken:' + token + ', viewModel:' + jsonData + '}';

          alert(dataString);

          $.ajax({
              url: '/Workflow/Index',
              cache: false,
              type: 'POST',
              contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: dataString,
              success: function (data) {
                  alert('success');
              }
          })
```

The controller has the definition:

```
    [RequiresAuthentication]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ValidateInput(true)]
    public ActionResult Index(CustomerCallViewModel viewModel, string workflowStep, PostedServiceSelections postedServiceSelections)
```

When the query fires, I get a 500 error, but I can't figure out 1) what the error actually is and 2) how to fix it so the query works.

I DID find a workaround by using this:

```
         $.ajax({
              url: '/Workflow/Index',
              type: 'POST',
              data: $("#mainForm").serialize(),
              success: function (data) {
                  alert('test');
              }
          });
```

But I'd like to understand where I went wrong in the previous attempt. Thoughts?

Thanks,
James

Comment: `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)` will send the initial model (unchanged) back to the controller so what is the point of this?

Comment: In that case, I must have misunderstood the purpose. This view has buttons on it that step forward and backward in a simple workflow - enter some data, click "next which updates the model behind the scene and reloads, etc. I'm trying to be able to post that data back via AJAX, using the model that contains data from the previous step + data on the current step. I'm new to MVC, so I am probably approaching it the wrong way.

Comment: It seems you are trying to create some kind of wizard. You might want to consider doing this all in one view with one form as [per this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to simplify this and use the mvc-ajax form helper.  It eliminates a lot of issues with using the script-based ajax calls.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Workflow", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "postSuccess" })
{
  // form fields here

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

<script>
  function postSuccess() {
    alert('test');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: That's a very cool solution - for anyone else looking, make sure to install the unobtrusive AJAX using Nuget. That said, I can't seem to make this work for me - there are several submit buttons on this view, each of which needs to do something different. Only one of them needs to push the @Model back to the controller.