# Validate Forms step by step

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I want to use ASP.NET MVC to create a registration page.

The registration page will have a single view and it will have multiple forms. The user can use "back" and "continue" buttons to go to a form (partial form).

First step:
On Form1, the user will enter his name, email and click "continue" which should do a postback and validate the form inputs. If form is valid, display form 2.

Second Step:
The user will add his company address and then click on "Done".

How can I create such a form in multiple steps?

---

I want to use ASP.NET MVC to create a registration page. The registration page will has a single URL and it will have many forms. The user can use "back" and "continue" buttons to go to a form (partial form). 
FIRST STEP: The user will enter his name, email, .. in Form1 Then he should click on "continue"--> Postback and validation of inputs. SECONED STEP: If Form1 is OK and the user has clicked the "continue"-button the second form (Form2) will appear. The user will add his company address and then click on "Done".

How can I create such a form in multiple steps?

Comment: Why not a single form where you validate each section of a form one step at a time as per [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)