# using Microsoft.Web.MVC on View

Tags: serialization, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following an online example for creating a wizard control. It involves in  serializing the model on the view, then pass it to the controller which Deserialize the model and use. Below is the code for the View,

```
@using Microsoft.Web.Mvc

@model Sample.Models.RegisterWizardViewModel

@{
var currentStep = Model.Steps[Model.CurrentStepIndex];
ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}
          @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {

                @Html.Serialize("wizard", Model)

                @Html.Hidden("StepType", Model.Steps[Model.CurrentStepIndex].GetType())
                @Html.EditorFor(x => currentStep, null, "")

                if (Model.CurrentStepIndex > 0)
                {
                    <input type="submit" value="Previous" name="prev" />
                }

                if (Model.CurrentStepIndex < Model.Steps.Count - 1)
                {
                    <input type="submit" value="Next" name="next" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="submit" value="Finish" name="finish" />
                }
            }
```

Now at first I was not finding [Deserialize] attribute in the controller and for that I have installed the MvcContrib package from the NuGet.

The problem I am facing is that @Html.Serialize("wizard", Model) is not found. Also the namespace Microsoft.Web.Mvc could not be resolved. If in the Controller file I use Microsoft.Web.Mvc then it work without a problem but when I use the same namespace in the view then it could not be resolved. What is the difference between System.Web.MVC and Microsoft.Web.MVC? How to resolved the namespace error?

I have also read that @Html.Serialize is not available and it can be accessible through MVC Futures. I have added the package but how to use it to Serialize the model on the View?

Edit: Just like to mention that I have installed the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures 5.0.0' but I am unable to see any reference in the references folder. There is no Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc or Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures reference in the references folder. Where did it go I wonder?

Comment: IMO this is a poor design - its trying to mimic Web Forms view state. Consider persisting each step to a database (`Session may also be an alternative), or use a single form with sections that are showm/hidden as required ([refer example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097))

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke Thanks for your reply. I was also not comfortable with the design either but this was the only do-able example that I was able to find. What I am trying to do is to create a Wizard control using JQuery Ajax with persisting each step information. I have found various examples but I want to do this with Partial Views. So at every step new partial view is loaded and when user click submit the value get persisted in session. Do you know any example or article that create MVC Wizard control using JQuery and Partial Views? You help will be highly appreciated,