# Basic wizard, and passing model from one view to another?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and trying to create a wizard-style series of views, passing the same model instance from one view to the next, where the user completes a little more information on each form. The controller looks something like this:-

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Step1(MyModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        return View("Step2", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Step2(MyModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        return View("Step3", model);
    }

    // etc..
```

Questions:-

1. When I submit the form from the Step1 view, it calls the Step1 POST method and results in the Step2 view being displayed in the browser. When I submit the form on *this* view, it calls the Step1 POST method again! I got it to work by specifying the action and controller name in `Html.BeginForm()`, so I'm guessing that the parameterless overload just POSTs back to the action that rendered the view?
2. I've noticed that the browser's address bar is out of sync with the current view - when I'm on the Step2 view it still shows the Step1 URL, and when on Step3 it shows the Step2 URL. What's going on?
3. Another approach I've seen for passing a model between views is to put the model in `TempData` then use `RedirectToAction()`. What are the pros and cons of this method versus what I'm currently doing?
4. I won't be providing any "back" buttons of my own in the wizard. Are there any pitfalls to be aware of regarding the browser's back button, and do either of the above two approaches help (or hinder)?

**Edit**

Prompted by @StephenMuecke's comment I've now rewritten this to use a single view. I tried this once before but had difficulties round-tripping a "step number" to keep track of where I was in the wizard. I was originally using a hidden field created with `@Html.HiddenFor', but this wasn't updating as the underlying model property changed. This appears to be "by design", and the workaround is to create the hidden field using vanilla HTML (`

Anyway the one-view wizard is now working. The only problem is the old chestnut of the user being able to click the back button after they have completed  the wizard, make a change, and resubmit a second time (resulting in a second DB record).

I've tried adding `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]` to my POST method, but all this does is display (in my case) a Chrome error page suggesting that the user clicks refresh to resubmit the form. This isn't user friendly and doesn't prevent a second submit.

Comment: Any reason why you don't use a single form where you show/hide each step?

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, and see my edit!

Comment: I was think more along the lines of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `RedirectToAction()` in this case without worrying about `TempData`. Just add your model as a parameter to each action and use `RedirectToAction("Step2", model)`;

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Step1()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Step2", model);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Step2(MyModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Step3", model);
}

// etc..
```

The answer to #1 is found in #2.. if you dont specify the Action in you `Html.BeginForm()` it posts to the current url.

Using TempData to avoid model displaying in url.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Step1()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);
    TempData["myModel"] = model;
    return RedirectToAction("Step2");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Step2()
{ 
    var model = TempData["myModel"] as MyModel;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);
    TempData["myModel"] = model;
    return RedirectToAction("Step3");
}

// etc..
```

Another option would be to add the name of the next action to ViewBag and set your actionName in each BeginForm()

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Step1()
{
    ViewBag.NextStep = "Step1";
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step1(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.NextStep = "Step1";
        return View(model);
    }

    ViewBag.NextStep = "Step2";
    return View("Step2", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Step2(MyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.NextStep = "Step2";
        return View(model);
    }
    ViewBag.NextStep = "Step3";
    return View("Step3", model);
}

//View
@using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.NextStep, "ControllerName")) 
{ 

}
```

I'd prefer to add NextStep as a property to MyModel and using that instead of using ViewBag though.

Comment: Just tried your `RedirectToAction` overload and I notice this results in the model properties appearing as querystring params in the URL. This is okay in my scenario but I guess it could be an issue if the model is particularly large?

Comment: true.. ill give you other options.

Comment: Don't use `TempData` for this. If the user refreshes any page in the wizard process, the whole thing fails. And avoid pass a model to a GET method. If the model contains properties which are complex objects or collection, binding will fail and you can easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

Comment: You just have to add `@{ TempData["myModel"] = Model; }` to you views to keep refreshes from causing problems.

Comment: Example  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6pVlnLi_JhTTF9FOEZZb2kyeFU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I understand the thought behind your approach and don't have any issues with it. Unfortunately, I don't believe that ASP.NET MVC is geared very well for passing the the same view model (with data!) between different actions.

Typically, the scaffolded actions in the controller will either create a model item or find it by identifier in the database.

I don't know if this would help, but you could try to save it to the database on every step, and then retrieve it by identifier, or you could also save it to a session and grab it that way.

One issue I do see with your approach is you have Step2 set as a get, yet you probably want to post data to it from Step1 instead of using a query string. You may need to reconcile that issue.