# How can we do group validation with in one form in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am a new in asp.net mvc. I have one begin-form but one more submit button. Each submit button want to do different group of validation. How can we do this scenario in asp.net mvc? can any one help me.

Comment: Can you let us know your validation methodology. Is it server side or client side. Also if possible provide code. Meanwhile you can refer  [this]( http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/cM1X161112-Handling-multiple-submit-buttons-on-the-same-form---MVC-Razor.html )

Comment: Not clear what you mean by _group validation_. Do you want to click a button and have it validate only certain controls (in which case why is it a submit button)? If you have a wizard type form where you step through sections of the form and want to validation each section individually, then refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)