# How to validate different parts of a form using jQuery validate?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form with a series of controls nested within it, and although I can get validation for the entire form to work, I need to validate different parts of the form at different times.

Say for example I have a form asking a user to fill out their personal details (name, address, etc.), but in the form there is option to include a number of addresses.  I need to be able to validate the form as a whole (addresses are not mandatory), but also separately validate the form that controls the input for the secondary addresses (i.e. when filling out a secondary address a user must enter a street, zip code, etc).  It will only be one form for the addresses, and each entered address will use the values to build up a string in a `<li></li>`.

I have done this before easily enough using Telerik Kendo whereby you can specify which containers to validate regardless of whether they are nested or not, so you can validate the main container and the child container separately, but I am just not sure how to do this with jQuery validate.  I also know nested forms is a standards violation, so I am not entirely sure how to approach this.

So essentially I need to create this sort of structure, where the button to save form validates that the user has specified at least a name and date of birth, but if adding an address that the user must enter the address details.

```
- Name (mandatory)
- Date of birth (mandatory)
- Addresses (optional)
----- [form to add addresses]
------ Address Line (mandatory)
------ City (mandatory)
------ State (mandatory)
------ Zip (mandatory)
------ Button to add address
- Gender (optional)
- Age (optional)
- Weight (optional)
- Button to save form
```

Comment: Are you dynamically adding the controls for new addresses?

Comment: No, the controls to add addresses will be loaded on first load.

Comment: Firstly, nested forms are invalid and will not work. You should consider dynamically adding the controls to include new addresses (refer [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29837547/set-class-validation-for-dynamic-textbox-in-a-table/29838689#29838689)). You can also validate groups of controls as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) but I don't think that going to help in your case

Comment: Aah, thanks, this has given me a decent idea of what route to take.

Answer (score -1):

Basically what you need to do is specify all the above controls in one form and decide the fields as which are always required and which are conditional.
for this purpose you can use MVC custom validations.Please follow link for the same.

[MVC Custom validations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC)

Comment: I don't see how this is going to work with my solution.  It doesn't solve the issue of a form within a form, and being able to validate the addresses on their own.