# form-group sections placing in different pages in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have following viewpage , Its form that contains text field, dropdowns and Rich text areas.

[image]

this is the [cshtml code](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/j89K8) for that viewpage

I want to restrict `Product_ID`, `ProductTypeID`, `ProductCategoryID`, `Subsidary_ID` to first page and from Product title onward add to second page .

like this view

[image]

How can I do this ?

Comment: You will need  3 different view models and 3 methods and 3 views. Is there ant reason you don't just use 3 sections within the one form and have next/back buttons that make the relevant section visible?

Comment: @StephenMuecke  can you refer example for this `use 3 sections within the one form and have next/back buttons that make the relevant section visible`

Comment: @RenanAraújo how can I use tabs , example would be highly appreciate

Comment: @kez, Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) for an example

Comment: @kez If you are using boostrap: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: @StephenMuecke as you mentioned I've changed like [this](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/nRprE) but then Next button is not working

Comment: What is not working? And have you added the css to hide the second and 3rd sections? Also, the script is referring to just `input` elements (`$.each(container.find('input'), function () {`) but you have `<select>` and `<textarea>` elements as well so the script needs to be modified to take those into account

Comment: I hope to do this using two sections , `Product_ID`, `ProductTypeID`, `ProductCategoryID`, `Subsidary_ID` in first section and other richtext areas in second section. once I integrate your solution , its showing `Next` button with first section and hidden  second section , but once I click next button I'm not getting any response

Comment: @StephenMuecke what can I do tor this

Comment: Start by changing the script to `$('.next').click(function () {` (you have given it a class name so best to use it). In the first line of code add `console.log('next');` and see what the output is in the browser console (remember the script wont do anything if the form controls are invalid)

Comment: @StephenMuecke once I changed script like this `$('.next').click(function () {
        console.log('next');` Im gewtting console window [like this](http://i.imgur.com/7TojwOG.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` scripts included in the view?

Comment: Yes I have `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` files in `Script` folder , for this view I'm refering scripts through Layout file , in that layout file using following statements     `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")` and `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")` I'm included scripts. I suppose this is right .

Comment: Use `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>` and `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>` or `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` (assuming you have the default bundles)

Comment: now this is working , thank you very much your help this much far, but exactly I want to restrict one rich editor for one page from 2nd section onward. , this rich text editor generating using that for loop each `i`th model object I want to setup as section ,How can do that

Comment: now this is working , thank you very much your help this much far, but exactly I want to restrict one rich editor for one page from 2nd page onward.These rich text editors generating using that `for` loop . each `i`th model object , I want to setup as section ,How can do that

Comment: @Chathz, Not sure what your saying - if you have the css `.section:not(:first-of-type) { display:none; }` then only the first section will be visible (clicking the 'next' button will display the next section)

Comment: @StephenMuecke now I can get Product_ID, ProductTypeID, ProductCategoryID, Subsidary_ID to first page. then I click next it showing the rest of all rich text editors in one page (which is 2nd page) . Actually I want to restrict one rich text editor per one page (literally one rich text editor per one section). since these all the text editors generating through [this loop](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/Common_Admin/bR9yE) I want configure it , please let me know whether you got it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95305/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create 3 separate view models with 3 separate views and 3 actions methods. Then in the POST method for the 1st view, save the data and redirect to the 2nd view as so on. Assuming you want the visual effect of only displaying a limited number of form controls in the view, a better solution would be to keep one view and inside the form tags, rendered sections with 'next/back' buttons to display only one section at a time. A simple example would be

View

```
<section>
    // first section controls
    <button class="next">Next</button>
</section>
<section>
    // second section controls
    <button class="next">Next</button>
</section>
```

CSS

```
section:not(:first-of-type) {
    display:none;
}
```

Script

```
$('.next').click(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('section');
    container.next('section').show();
    container.hide();
});
```

With the last section in the form containing a submit button to post the form back to the controller.

Refer also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) for more detail on implementing client side validation to ensure the form controls in the current section are valid before moving to the next section.