# How to customize ASP.net MVC jquery unobtrusive validation message display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

by default MVC use  jquery unobtrusive validation lib to show validation message at client side. suppose i have small form with two textbox for first name and last name. when click submit button then client side validation will fire and display all validation message at once. but i want to display validation message one by one. now tell me where to customize the code and what code need to add or modify in js to make it possible.

### here is my small sample code

```
namespace MVC_myfirst_Mvcapplication.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string First { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Last { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }

    }

}
```

### Controller : PersonController.cs

```
public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        PersonContext db = new PersonContext();
        //
        // GET: /Person/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var People = db.People.ToList();
            return View(People);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Person/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Person/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Person Person)
        {

            db.People.Add(Person);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }


    }
```

### View:

```
@model MVC_myfirst_Mvcapplication.Models.Person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Person</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Birthdate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Birthdate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Birthdate)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

tell me which code i need to change in js to show validation message one-by-one in a specific div? thanks

Comment: You can use jquery to validate individual elements using `$("form").validate().element(someElement);` and test `.valid()` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) for an example (but why would you want to do this?)

Comment: whatever your said...can u redirect me to right article so i can read and can see how to write code to handle this.