# Submitting an MVC form using JavaScript and still generating an AntiForgeryToken

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I ran into a scenario where I have to programmatically submit an asp.net MVC form using JavaScript (form.Submit()) when the user clicks a button outside of the form tags.

I believe when this is the case, none of the built-in ASP.NET MVC functionality is applied. Please correct me if I am wrong.

1. No AntiForgery token is validated (which should work with the Controller tag [ValidatAntiForgeryToken])
2. Unobtrusive validation does not work

I am assuming that in this scenario there really isn't much of an option but to figure out another way to handle CSRF. Additionally, another way to handle client-side validation, not being able to validate based on model data-annotations.

Comment: The ValidatAntiForgeryToken *will* be processed sever-side if specified. It must be present in the posted payload, but form.serialize() will do that. Unobtrusive validation will be bypassed as it hooks into the form `submit` event

Comment: Alright, so your saying I don't have to worry about the ValidateAntiForgeryToken since it will be sent when using AJAX and data: $('#myForm').serialize()... But as far as unobtrusive validation along with the model I am basically stuck using jQuery Validation to manually validate everything, without relying on the ViewModel annotations. Correct?

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye The reason I am asking about this unobtrusive validation thing is because I am using a single form with a wizard approach using jQuery steps. Everytime the continue button is clicked that is not the actual submit button I would like to still use Unobtrusive validation to validate each step... I guess this isn't possible. I wonder why there is no way to manually call unobtrusive validation.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you call unobtrusive validation yourself (just been information I can no longer contribute to SO from work, so good luck with this).

Comment: @GoneCodingGoodbye Thanks for the info! I am yet to find any examples on something like that.

Comment: @BlakeRivell, You can _use unobtrusive validation to validate each step_ (and I gave you a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) showing how this can be done in one of your [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35279785/using-built-in-asp-net-mvc-validation-with-a-wizard-approach))

Comment: @StephenMuecke I do not want to use another third-party validation library. I want to stick with only using jQuery Validation and jQuery Unobtrusive Validation libraries.

Comment: The link I gave you is not _another third-party validation library_ Its just using `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`