# Sharing same ViewModel across tabs within same page?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

The parent partial view uses a ViewModel with 3 sub models within.

```
@using MyDomain.ViewModel.EventViewModel
```

It has 5 tabs as following:

```
<div class="tab-pane active tabClass" id="tabs-1">
    @Html.Partial("_tab1", Model)
</div>
<div class="tab-pane active tabClass" id="tabs-2">
    @Html.Partial("_tab2", Model)
</div>
<div class="tab-pane active tabClass" id="tabs-3">
    @Html.Partial("_tab3", Model)
</div>
<div class="tab-pane active tabClass" id="tabs-4">
    @Html.Partial("_tab4", Model)
</div>
<div class="tab-pane active tabClass" id="tabs-5">
    @Html.Partial("_tab5", Model)
</div>
```

There is a form within each tab that user needs to fill out and click next to move on to next tab. At the last tab, he/she can hit submit to send everything (the ViewModel) to controller/action and direct to another page.

My question is if I pass the model into these 5 partial views in such a way, will there be 5 different copies/instances or will there be just one shared amongst them? The reason I asked is because I was afraid each tab has its own instance of the ViewModel, and when the submit button is hit in the last tab, only input from that tab is saved to the model and submitted (in other words, input from tab1-4 is not recorded)

Comment: If there is a form in each tab and you submit the last form, only the values in that form will be submitted

Comment: If you want data from all the tabs, you may keep the form outside(of all your 5 tabs)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: thank you. Thats what I'm afraid. Does wrapping 5 tabs within BeginForm help (only 1 submit button on the last tab)?

Comment: Yes, you would need only one `<form>` tag (although using tabs for this is probably not the best option, especially if you have any validation applied to model properties. A wizard approach as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) might be a better option (although you have not given enough info to be sure what your trying to do)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thank you. I intended to write couple of functions to validate the input at the end of each tab before allowing user to move to the next one. This is already discussed and given to me so I cant really change much

Comment: The answer I linked to shows you how to validate the controls within a container - just adapt it to validate the controls withing each `<<div class="tab-pane" .. >` when moving to a new tab :)

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, a single instance of the ViewModel is used to render the partial views. Once the page is rendered, the ViewModel itself doesn't persist. It's only a HTML page.

It's the name attributes of the input fields that match the properties of the ViewModel. When the form is submitted, the data will deserialized into your ViewModel based on the matching name attributes. As long as they are correctly named, you should be good.

Make sure to put all inputs (all tabs) into a single form.