# MVC Partial Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a view that is divided in half. On the left half is a couple of text boxes and a button. On the second half are a couple more text boxes and another button. In my model, I have `[Required]` attributes on all my text boxes and when I push either button, the client side validation is kicking in telling me the fields are required, which is what's expected.

My question is, is there a way to make it so that when I click the button on the left, it will only validate the controls on the left. And when I click the right button, make it validate only the controls on the right?

Comment: Keep it in 2 separate forms ?

Comment: @Shyju Can you show me an example?

Comment: If its a single form, you can validate individual controls (or groups of controls) as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Comment: I'm confused by everyone's usage of the word "forms". When I hear "forms", I think of WebForms. This is MVC. So when everybody say forms, do they mean HTML form tags or do you mean views?

Comment: HTML `<form>` tags :)

Answer (score 0):

you must use 2 forms. in this case i, personally, use 2 different partial so i can use two models and validations

Comment: When you say "forms", are you talking about views? Or are you talking about HTML `form` tags?