# One big form with a few steps -Validation issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a MVC Order Form that has 4 steps in it.

The user clicks on "NEXT" on the first step -> the second steps opens etc...

On my View Model I have one object that is composed from **all the fields of all the 4 forms**.

How can I on the forth form, on submit, to post to the server the data of all the 4 forms?

I did it this way (4 forms) for validation purpose, so I can validate each form before moving to the next step.

I show/hide the forms with jquery.

My Order View (example without design etc..)

```
<div>
<form id="formStep1">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="sellerFirstName" class="required" />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="sellerLastName" class="required" />
    <button id="submitStep1">Next</button>
</form>
<form id="formStep2">
    <label>Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" name="propertyAddress" />
    <label>City</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" name="propertyCity" />
    <label>State</label>
    <input type="text" class="required" name="propertyState" />
    <button type="submit" class="orderf02" id="submitStep2">Next</button>
</form>
<form id="formStep3">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="buyerFirstName" class="required" />
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="buyerLastName" class="required" />
    <button type="submit" class="orderf02" id="submitStep3">Next</button>
</form>
<form id="formStep4" method="POST" action="Order/SubmitOrder">
    <input type="file" id="file1">
    <input type="text" id="file1text" />
    <button class="orderf02" type="submit" id="submitStep4">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

My Order object:

```
public class Order
{
//First Step
public string sellerFirstName { get; set; }
public string sellerMiddleName { get; set; }

//Second Step
public string propertyAddress { get; set; }
public string propertyCity { get; set; }
public string propertyState { get; set; }

//Third Step
public string buyerFirstName { get; set; }
public string buyerLastName { get; set; }

//Forth Step
public HttpPostedFileBase file1 { get; set; }
public string file1text { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can create one form and add steps to different divs, *show/hide* them with *JavaScript/jQuery* and post at the end

Comment: @AdilMammadov I edited my question as per your comment, if I will do so I will run into an issue with the validation.

Comment: You can only post one form at a time. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) for one solution to solving this which addresses the validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose you need to create one form add inputs for different steps into different *containers* (for example `div`), then navigate between those containers using *JavaScript* or *jQuery* and post in the end. To solve your validation problem add function which validates specific container:

```
// Validate every input element inside div.
// Return false if any element fails validation.
function validateElementsInsideContainer(container, validator) {
    var isCurrentDivValid = true;

    if (container && validator) {
        $(container).find("input").each(function () {
            if (!validator.element($(this))) {
                isCurrentDivValid = false;
            }
        });
    }

    return isCurrentDivValid;
}
```

Then call this function for *containers* on each step change and navigate only if valid:

```
var validator = $("form").validate();

function toSecondStep() {
    var firstStep = $("#first-step");
    var secondStep = $("#second-step");

    // Validate
    var isValid = validateElementsInsideContainer(firstStep, validator);

    if(isValid) {
        firstStep.hide();
        secondStep.show();
    }
}
```

### Update:

The main method here is [validator.element()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/). You can pass whatever input you want and it will validate it. For example, if you want to validate according to some filter you can do it as well. Add function similar to `validateElementsInsideContainer` like below:

```
function validateSpecificElements(elements, validator) {
    var elementsAreValid = true;

    if (elements && validator) {
        $(elements).each(function () {
            if (!validator.element($(this))) {
                elementsAreValid = false;
            }
        });
    }

    return elementsAreValid;
}
```

Then you can select inputs according to what you want and validate them:

```
var validator = $("form").validate();

function toSecondStep() {
    var firstStep = $("#first-step");
    var secondStep = $("#second-step");

    // Get elements to validate
    var elementsToValidate = $("form").find(".sepcific-element-class");     
    var isValid = validateSpecificElements(elementsToValidate, validator);

    if(isValid) {
        firstStep.hide();
        secondStep.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but just one approach, your code will validate all the inputs in the form, how can I validate just a part of them? Thanks!!

Comment: @user3378165, it will validate elements inside container, for example inside div.

Comment: I understand that, the problem is that I don't want to validate **all** the elements within the `div`, I need just **a part of them**, maybe can I define it with a `class`?

Comment: @user3378165, you can add as many containers as you want. For example, In one form you can have 10 containrs and you can validate them seperatelly. Additionally, of course you can select and validate them using class. You can alter `validateElementsInsideContainer` method to accepts elements inside of container and validate them one by one. The purpose of `container` in that method is for being able to get elements inside it.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of how to validate elements on a `container` based on a spesific class? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be exactly wht I am looking for. I tried that but for some reason it's not working, it's returning `false` even if all the fields are filled out.

Comment: @user3378165, may be your validation does not work as expected. Please debug and see which input fails validation and double check your validation rules

Comment: I found the issue but not sure how to solve it, it validates all the inputs with the spesific class in the form, not just the ones that are on the current div. Any idea why? I have to validate every time on the current  `div` the elements that have the class I specified.

Comment: @user3378165, beacuse I selected all elements with *sepcific-element-class* inside form with this line `var elementsToValidate = $("form").find(".sepcific-element-class");`. Change it to `var elementsToValidate = $("#your-div-name").find(".sepcific-element-class");` if you want to validate inputs with specific class in specific div

Comment: Working perfectly!! Thank you soooo mcuh!!