# Dividing the main view in MVC to multiple sub views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to create a view that that is divided internally  into many sub views 
that will be displayed beside each other, i.e

The view will contains something like steps that when user fill one of the sub views he should click next button on the sub view to show the next sub view which will be displayed directly beside the old sub view .

I am using c# , MVC5 , JavaScript , Jquery .

i am thinking about creating ViewModel that conatins all my data of all sub views from all required tables , then create a view that is strongly typed to that view model .

In the strongly typed view , i am thinking to create a main Div html element that will contain another sub div elements (will be displayed Horizontally beside each other) and there will be a horizontal scroll to scroll through these sub div elements, each of them have fixed width and contains also a part of the fields for a certain part of data ,

in the first load of the page , there will be only the first sub div which will be visible to the user and it contains a tabular data , when user click on one line of this data it should show only the second sub div and an editable fields to be filled or edited and a button with text continue , when user clicks on the butoon continue on the second sub div view , it should display the third div element that will also contain some editable fields and a next button , when user click on that button it should display the fourth div ...etc , and at the final step it should display a submit button to save the data in all this divs elements and at the same time firs the validations of the page.

i am trying to find another solution rather than using partial views , it this idea will gonna work , because i have no time to implement and test , i should give a quick decision ,

Or if there is a better solution , i would be happy to know it .

i also need the submit button at the end, to horizontally scroll automatically to the sub div if it contains a validation error.

i am Open for any suggestions regarding this but i don't want to use Angular or NodeJS.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) for one option

Comment: *"rather than using partial views"* - partial views are a means to an end, not the end itself.  Consider how this would work from a final-rendered version (regardless of how it got there) - as the submit is at the end, most likely it would be a large form containing a number of `div`s that show/hide as required.   To generate this you could have a single view.

Comment: @freedomn ,,, i am not pretty sure that i have got ur point , but what i am thinking to do is large form containing a number of div s that show/hide as required and yes i want to create a single view that will be strongly types to a view model that contains all my information from all tables , so do u recomend a partial view or u recommend this solution

Comment: I certainly don't recommend "*a*" partial view...  partial views have 2 uses: 1) reuse (eg a "context summary" section on every page and 2) managability (breaking up a large "thing" into smaller, maintainable chunks).  If your form is 500 lines long, you could use a number of partials to make it easier to work with, eg one per page.  But there's no reason to just for the sake of using a partial view.

Comment: @freedomm ,,,, okay Great , then i am going to use only one large view as the contents as i know will not be going to be used anywhere else