# How to send one value after successful ajax post request to a page redirect

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5

I am learning ASP.net MVC - 5 and I am stuck at one problem. So I need to open a URL after successful Ajax Post Request. But I also want to pass one value to the new URL's Controller Action. Below is what I have till now.

**AJAX CALL**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,

        success: function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
            int TEMPVAR = 2;
            DisplayError('Save Successful', 'Success', function () { 
            window.location.href = '/Settings/Customize/'; });
            },
            error: function (error) {
        }
    });
```

**Controller Action**

```
  [AuthorizeSettings]
  public ActionResult Customize()
  {
     //I want to be able to access TEMPVAR value here
     // code removed for brevity
     return View(configData);
  }
```

**Question:** How to pass the `TEMPVAR data` to the `Customize Action`

**Points:**

I know there are some ways to pass data. TempData,Viewbag,SessionVariable, Embedding the TEMP value in URL Request,  Anonymous Objects, ViewData, Static variable for the class, Global Variable, JSON. But I am totally confused how to pass data. I am newbiew please guide me here.

**EDIT:**

**AJAX CALL**

```
 $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,

        success: function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
            int TEMPVAR = 2;
            DisplayError('Save Successful', 'Success', function () { 
            window.location.href = '/Settings/Customize/'; });
             TEMPDATA["value"] = TEMPVAR;
            },
            error: function (error) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: You should be able to access `TempData`, if it has been accessed yet.

Comment: @Win: You mean to say I need to set TEMPVAR data into TEMPData[]

Comment: I have a variable let's say TEMPVAR I need to pass it to Customize controller action after Sucessful POST Request.

Comment: Yes, you will need to set data as TempData["SomeName"]. Then you can retrieve later.

Comment: @Win Thanks a ton! Can you kindly see my edits.

Comment: What is the URL in Javascript code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149820/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-win).

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page. To make a ajax call and then immediately redirect is crazy. Just make a normal submit and redirect in the POST method and pass the value as a route parameter (`TempData` only lasts one request and if the user refreshes the browser it will all fail and an exception will probably be thrown)

Comment: I am using a `http://www.jquery-steps.com/` plug in on my page. And it renders submit button on its own. And when I click on submit button there is one event "OnFinishing{}" (refer the documentation) which gets invoked. I just wrote the ajax call inside OnFinishing{} event. I am not sure, how can I make a normal POST request from there.

Comment: I totally understood what you told though. But I am not sure how I would achieve it from inside of onFinishing{} event.

Comment: @StephenMuecke `http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples`

Comment: @Unbreakable, Not familiar with that plugin, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097) is how I approach 'wizard' (no plugin required)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Thanks for your reply. Just wondering, if we are using certain plug in which generates Submit button on the fly. I mean via their javascript code. And then they have event such as "onFinishing{}" which gets called/fired. How can we make a normal POST request from a JS event.If I have my button in my cshtml file then I can make a POST request easily but what if some plug in is rendering the Submit Button and some event is getting fired on click on that. Then how one would make a normal POST request. Anyways thank you so much for your guidance. :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I looked into your answer. It's nice and simple. :)

Comment: If its a submit button, then just clicking it should submit the form. Not sure why you need to do it in an js event, but if so then you can just use `$('form').submit();`

Comment: Ya. That should work fine. I will try it. Currently as the documentation told that on the final button click "OnFinishing' event will get fired, so I wrote the AJAX POST Logic there. But I think you solution will work too. I will give it a try. :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/unbreakable/o2gxgz9r/9543/ ... This is the JS Fiddle of that plug in I talked about. I have added the onFinishing section in the HTML section. And it gets fired on clicking finish/submit button.

Comment: In the bottom of HTML Section I have the `onFinishing{}`  code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149859/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-unbreakable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, you want to send data from `SaveStyles` to `Customize`. If so, you can use `TempData` -

```
public class PersistController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveStyles()
    {
        TempData["Status"] = true;
        TempData["Val"] = 4;
        return Json(true);
    }
}

public class SettingsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Customize()
    {
        bool status = Convert.ToBoolean(TempData["Status"]);
        int val = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["Val"]);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because of you guys only, beginner like me gets confident to move forward in their career. It worked flawlessly. I have used TempData before But I have used it while interacting directly between two controller actions. Never thought it this way via ajax and all. And after seeing this answer it all makes sense. As temp data is more like concurrent call based. It does not care if its via ajax or a "redirect".

Comment: Just one small point. I saw many answers where users were doing some modification in the success result of ajax post method. Which one is better way. Shall I follow the temp data approach or try to modify the ajax post request. Please guide.

Comment: So basically you dont want me to modify  anything here.  `success: function (result) {
            if (result == true) {
            int TEMPVAR = 2;
            DisplayError('Save Successful', 'Success', function () { 
            window.location.href = '/Settings/Customize/'; });
            },
            error: function (error) {
        }`

Comment: If you pass *sensitive* data between pages, you *definitely* want to use TempData. Otherwise, you can use data return from Ajax Post method, and pass it to Customize method.