# validating specific form fields in jquery in a asp.net mvc razor page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I need advice! I have a asp.net mvc razor page where I have a large form for submitting bank account details and other info needed for verifying bank details like address, last 4 ssn, country, state, etc, etc. I thought I could create a large form with 3 div's ('billingContainer', 'addressContainer', 'accountContainer') where each div contained related fields and then have a 'next' and 'back' button at the bottom of each container. Then in javascript/jquery check for those specific fields to be valid in each container. If say for example the address fields are valid then I would enable the "next" button to show/display the 'accountContainer', then when all of those fields are checked and valid I could submit. So to the user it looks like there are 2-3 pages that are traversed only when the fields on each page are all valid! Is this the best way or should I create forms for each of the different containers and do a full post with each form saving the data in the viewmodel along the way?

Quetion - how can I check for validation for all the fields in just one container - say, the 'addressContainer', so I can then enable the next button and show the next part of the form 'accountContainer'? Then if the user removes text from one field and invalidates it, I would disable the next button so he/she can't move on to the next container?

Here is my html with razor code, showing each section has a div around it with a container name that I will show and hide

```js
$(".showAddressContainerBtn").off('click').on('click', function() {
  $("#billingContainer").hide();
  $("#addressContainer").show();
  $("#Country1").prop('disabled', true);


  $(".showBillingContainerBtn").off('click').on('click', function() {
    $("#billingContainer").show();
    $("#addressContainer").hide();
  });

  $(".showAccountContainerBtn").off('click').on('click', function() {
    $("#addressContainer").hide();
    $("#accountContainer").show();

    $(".showAddressContainerFromAccountBtn").off('click').on('click', function() {
      $("#addressContainer").show();
      $("#accountContainer").hide();


    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="bankForm">
  <div id="billingContainer">
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Billing Country</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountryId, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "Country", @class = "btn-group-lg countryList form-control selectpicker" })
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <h2>Payout methods in United States</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.TransferType, "bankaccount", new { id = "BankAccount", data_label = "" })
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-11">
        <div>Bank transfer in USD ($)</div>
        <div>Get paid in 5-7 business days</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <hr />
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-link" href="/User/Payout" style="border: 1px solid #286090"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> back</a>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right showAddressContainerBtn">Next <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="addressContainer" style="display: none">
    <div class="row">
      <h3>What's the address for this payout method?</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="AddressLine1">Street address</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine1, new { @id = "AddressLine1", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 123 Main St." }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine1,
        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="AddressLine2">Apt, suite, bldg. (optional)</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine2, new { @id = "AddressLine2", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. Apt #6" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StreetAddressLine2,
        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 5px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="City">City</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @id = "City", @class = "form-control input-lg" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 0px;">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="State">State / Province</label> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateCode, new SelectList(Model.StateList, "Value", "Text"), "", new { @id = "State", @class = "btn-group-lg countryList form-control selectpicker" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m
          => m.StateCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PostalCode">Zip code / Postal code</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PostalCode, new { @id = "PostalCode", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 94102" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PostalCode, "", new { @class
        = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountryId, new SelectList(Model.CountryList, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "Country1", @class = "btn-group-lg countryList form-control selectpicker" })
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <hr />
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-link showBillingContainerBtn" style="border: 1px solid #286090"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> back</a>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right showAccountContainerBtn">Next <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="accountContainer" style="display: none;">

    <div class="row">
      <h2>Add bank account info</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="LastFour">Last 4 SSN</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastFour, new { @id = "LastFour", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 4530" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastFour, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="AccountName">Account holder name</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AccountName, new { @id = "AccountName", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. First Last" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.AccountName, "", new {
        @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Routing">Routing number</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Routing, new { @id = "Routing", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 123456789" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Routing, "", new { @class = "text-danger"
        })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Account">Account number</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Account, new { @id = "Account", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 1234567890" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Account, "", new { @class = "text-danger"
        })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ConfirmAccount">Confirm account number</label> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmAccount, new { @id = "ConfirmAccount", @class = "form-control input-lg", placeholder = "e.g. 1234567890" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmAccount,
        "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-link showAddressContainerFromAccountBtn" style="border: 1px solid #286090"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> back</a>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right addAccountBtn">Next <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: For validating groups of controls, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097)

Answer (score 0):

how can I check for validation for all the fields in just one container - say, the 'addressContainer', so I can then enable the next button and show the next part of the form 'accountContainer'?

Solution: I would suggest you to perform inline validation on every field step by step and then if a user validate all the fields then allow him to perform some action or post back to server.for more information kindly view that link [Click here for inline validation plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Minimal-Inline-Form-Validation-Plugin-For-jQuery-Valideater.html)

[also you can get some help from here](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)

Then if the user removes text from one field and invalidates it, I would disable the next button so he/she can't move on to the next container?

solution: You can use onTextChange functions stuff like that again as a whole complete solution in your case will be inline validation.