# Displaying correct panel using jQuery.Validate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a tabbed panel like below:

[image]

Student tab has StudentName and Mark tabs has Math. This is my Model:

```
public class StudentViewModel 
{
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Math { get; set; }
}
```

This is the View for the above tabbed panel:

```
<form action="~/Controller/Action" method="Post" id="myFormId">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="Student">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.StudentName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.StudentName)
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="Mark">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Math)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Math)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
```

The entire tabbed panel is inside 1 form and I am using jQuery.Validate to 
validate the form when user submits the form.

What I want is to switch to Mark tab, if there is a validation message on Math field and there is no error on Student name. What is the best approach to achieve this using jQuery.Validate?

Comment: Are you also using mvc's client side validation using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`? (you do not have any `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` elements)

Comment: Sorry my bad, yes I am. I will update my question.

Comment: In that case you can validate individual controls, or groups of controls using `Validator.element(element)`

Comment: No time just now, but will add example in 30 min or so

Comment: @StephenMuecke, perfect thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to test if the form is valid, and if not, find the `<span>` elements generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and check if they contain the `field-validation-error` class. If so, switch to its parent `<div class="tab-pane">` element.

I am assuming that your tabs actually contain multiple form controls (if not, then you could probably simplify the following)

```
var tabs = $('.tab-pane'); // get all the tabs
$('#myFormId').submit(function() {
    if(!$(this).valid()) { // check if the form is valid
        $.each(tabs, function(index, item) {
            // Test if any errors for form controls in the tab
            if($(this).find('.field-validation-error').length > 0) { 
                // Change the active tab
                tabs.removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
                return false; // exit the $.each() loop
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note that the above code will activate the first tab containing invalid controls.

Another option would be to use the `Validator.element(element)` function as described in [MVC Force jQuery validation on group of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25643394/mvc-force-jquery-validation-on-group-of-elements/25645097#25645097), although that is probably more appropriate code to run when you switch between tabs (i.e. to prevent moving to another tab if there are validation errors on the current tab)